# Inapp billing android - No checkout screen

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am a newbie to android and i want to have a feature of inapp buying. The user will purchase the full version one time only. I do not want any checkout screen to appear. Instead I just want to show a message that "Do you want to purchase abc product for $2?" If user chooses yes then i should get a response from google if purchase successful or not.

I am following Blundell blog [tutorial](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment) to achieve the functionality. When I call request for "REQUEST_PURCHASE", I recieve response bundle which contains pending intent.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = (PendingIntent) response.get("PURCHASE_INTENT");

pendingIntent.send(context, 0, new intent());
```

I get a blank screen. When I move away from this blank screen, the broadcast receiver is activated and I receive "Purchase successful" in OnRecieve method of receiver. I am using test product "android.test.item_purchased". I do not want any blank screen, i just want to get the response in my activity class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work like this. Purchases are handled by the Google Play Store app, and will show a GUI to let the user select a payment method and approve the purchase. That would give users the assurance that they are indeed paying Google (which in turn pays you) and not some random scam app. So this is a good thing.

Not sure where you get your blank screens from, you need to show more code. And that is really a separate question.